# Bind a GridView to a single object

Tags: gridview, telerik, radgridview

I'm trying to bind a single row to a Telerik RadGridView, but I think this question might apply to any GridView control.  Since this list only ever contains one item, it seems inefficient to bind to a "List", even though I know that List only has one item.  However, when I try to just bind to a single item in my list, nothing happens.  Nothing shows up on my grid, but I don't get an error in the debugger.

This works.  GetObjects is a Dal method that returns a List.

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = MyDal.GetObjects(myID);
this.myGridView.DataSource = myObjects;
```

The following code does NOT work.  GetObject is a Dal method that only returns the first element from a List.

```
MyObject myObject = MyDal.GetObject(myID);
this.myGridView.DataSource = myObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code but I bound it to object called class1 and it works so fine using this method:

```
List<MyObject> _list1=new List<MyObject>();
_list1.Add(MyDal.GetObject(myID));
RadGrid1.DataSource=_list1;
RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

the reason is  Grid Should only be bound to IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Regards